# Port forwarding and C++ Winsock Client-Server applications

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

As the title says, I'm creating a TCP client and a server program in C++. My question is, when running the client and server on two separate machines that go through a different firewalled router over the internet, does it matter which router has ports forwarded?  Ex. Can just the router used by the client machine have the correct TCP ports forwarded and the client server connection be established?

Comment: Is the server expected to lack it's own public IP address? Also are _all_ TCP connections between these two programs initiated by the client? Please edit your original question to contain this information, so I (or another user) can answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all TCP connections these programs use are initiated by the client, the router on the server's network will need to be configured with static port address translation (forwarding all connections for the specified port to your application server) **OR** the server will need its own public IP.

The router on the client's side will also need to perform Port Address Translation, but can do so dynamically. This does not ordinarily require any special configuration.

If your server can initiate a TCP session with the client, things get more complicated.